# How to change the title on each page custom in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to change the title on each page to custom in React-Admin
Is there a specific property in the Recorse or list or edit or create composites?
please guide me
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iULcE.png)

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far please

Answer (score 4):

List, Show, Create and Update components all accept title prop, it can be either a string, or an element of your own.

```
<List {...props} title="My custom title">
    ...
</List>
```

or

```
const PostTitle = props => {
    return <span>Post {props.record ? `"${props.record.title}"` : ''}</span>;
};

export const PostShow = (props) => (
    <Show title={<PostTitle />} {...props}>
        ...
    </Show>
);
```

If you wanna change the name in the menu, you can pass options prop with label to Resource:

```
<Resource ... options={{label: "Custom menu name"}}>
```

For multillingual apps, this is accomplished with the i18nProvider prop on Admin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set page titles for web browsers, or any other properties on `<head>` block, you can use [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet).

```
  <Helmet>
  <title>New page title</title>
  </Helmet>
```

Here some references:

- [How to Use React Helmet – With Example Use Case](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-helmet-examples/)
- [What is React Helmet and Where To Use It](https://dev.to/olenadrugalya/what-is-react-helmet-and-where-to-use-it-2ed3)
- Dynamic window title [#5893](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5893) (github discussion about use helmet on react-admin framework to set header titles).